# Order by Field with two substring

Tags: mysql

The server is returning me the values

```
id, dia_hora
1   SEG-20h
2   SEG-09h
3   QUI-11h
4   SEX-09h
```

This query work for acronyms

```
select * from agenda_padrao ORDER BY (
   FIELD(SUBSTRING(dia_hora,1,3), 'DOM', 'SEG', 'TER', 'QUA', 'QUI', 'SEX', 'SAB')
 )
```

but i need first sort acronyms and then the two numbers in ascending order

like this

```
2   SEG-09h
1   SEG-20h
3   QUI-11h
4   SEX-09h
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mysql function [FIELD()](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_field.asp) to assign the order.

```
ORDER BY FIELD(SUBSTRING(dia_hora,1,3), 'DOM', 'SEG', 'TER', 'QUA', 'QUI', 'SEX', 'SAB'),
         cast(substring(dia_hora, 5,6) as unsigned)
```

Comment: You know the drill: please add some explanation, or it pops in in the low quality post alert. :)